# JBoss AS 6, Eclipse, Seam 2.2 - Servlet don´t show up

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jboss, seam

I use JBoss AS 6 with Seam 2.2 in Eclipse. I had create a simple Seam 2 Web Project, (I think with seam gen) and now I wanted to add servlet.

*File->New->Servlet*

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("Hello post!");
        writer.close();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("Hello get!");
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

In `web.xml` there is also the servlet registrated.

Okay, but when I compile all and go to localhost:8080/mypage/test the page get loaded but no output is visible (also not in the sourcecode of the page).

Comment: Did you redeploy the project and restart the server? Is the `doGet()` method really called? (put a debug breakpoint and so on). Also show the `web.xml`. You're by the way printing wrong messages.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to deploy my ***-dx.xml. :)
What do you mean with *printing* wrong messages?

Comment: OK, I reposted it as an answer. As to the messages, read and compare them with the `doXXX()` method where you're printing them.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms indicate that your project isn't properly deployed. Make sure that your project is properly built and deployed and that the server is cleanly restarted.